# Pattern to clean up Smart Ptr from container that doesn't have ownership

Tags: c++, memory

I need to hold a smart pointer in a map. The map does not own the object, but there are multiple shared_ptrs to the object elsewhere.

How can I ensure the key is removed from this map once all other shared_ptrs to the object are destroyed, without periodically polling the map?

Comment: How about.  Store a raw pointer in the map.  Use a custom deleter for the shared_ptr that holds a reference to the map and remove the key/value from the map when the custom deleter gets called.

Comment: I was thinking something along those lines (in my case I could just handle it in the class destructor since this object will always be allocated with a  smart ptr), but I was wondering if there is a generally prescribed pattern for handling this, since the problem doesn't seem like it would be that rare. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shared_ptr` can be provided with a `deleter` which can help in deleting the object. Inside this `deleter` you can update the `map` accordingly.

For example refer: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Answer (score 2):

If "without polling" you mean that you would like `std::shared_ptr` to handle everything for you then know that this is not a feature of `std::shared_ptr`. True, a `shared_ptr` knows about its current use count but it does not receive any signals to update it of any changes.

You can however have a solution that performs checks sometimes but not all the time.

I would suggest using a `std::map` that holds [std::weak_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) instead of `std::shared_ptr`. You will need to run a check to see which ptrs are invalid and remove them. How often to check will be up to you. You can for instance check your map only when you are adding a new item and there are more than 20,000 items in your map.

Comment: There are ways I can think of doing it, using the destructor or a custom deleter. I didn't consider checking the map based on size rather than a period interval, thanks for that.

Comment: If you go with this solution then it's important to make sure that you use std::weak_ptr instead of std::shared_ptr otherwise you will only be freeing up memory whenever you clean your map which might not be often.

Comment: @Kindread Using a destructor/custom deleter is one way of doing it as long as you are ok with them knowing about your map.